# Difference tow type of Shp File

Tags: gis, geojson, shapefile

i have two type of *.SHP file.
in QGIS when i get Layer properties seee this Information 
[image]

this is true format 
[image]
this is false format

how can i change picture 2 format to picture one format ?
what is difference between two file 
i see only extent is different and how can change extent of SHP File 
how to get GEOJSON File from this SHP File

Answer (score 0):

You are right that it can't be a correct extent in EPSG 4326, but then either the extent is wrong, or the CRS is wrong, or the file is corrupted.

You can try to update the extent: Layer->Layer Properties->Source->Update extent
but I doubt this will solve the problem.

Or you can try to guess the projected coordinate system of the second layer (epsg 32640?)

Comment: i try to this but didn't change extent . do you think i must be get again ?

Comment: I can only guess, because I don't know your data. My guess is the two layers have two different coordinate systems. The first is a geographic one, units are degrees; if it is EPSG 4326, the extent is compatible with a place some 40Km NE out of Masshad (Iran). The second is a projected coordinate system, units are usually meters; if it is EPSG 32640, the extent is compatible with a place some 40Km NW out of Masshad (Iran). You may want to take a look at https://docs.qgis.org/3.10/en/docs/gentle_gis_introduction/coordinate_reference_systems.html